# X11/XQuartz won't auto-launch after upgrading to OS X Mavericks?

Tags: macos, mac, wireshark, osx-mavericks, xquartz

I can't use Wireshark on latest OS X 10.9 Mavericks.

Previously, I was using XQuartz to run X11 applications like Wireshark.

But, yesterday, after I upgraded my iMac operating system to OS X 10.9, I got this:

[image]

But I had installed it before I upgraded OS X.
[image]

How can I get Wireshark / X11 / XQuartz to run again after upgrading to Mavericks?

Comment: Why not simply re-install X11?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Re-install XQuartz 2.7.4 (the latest version as of this writing).

I saw the same problem. I already had XQuartz 2.7.4 installed and working with Wireshark before I installed Mavericks. After installing Mavericks and trying to launch Wireshark, I got the same dialog you did. Re-installing XQuartz 2.7.4 solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem and was able to fix it by re-installing the latest version of XQuartz and updating Java.

Using Matlab R2010aSV and it opens and runs now in Mavericks just like it used to before I upgraded from Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling XQuartz worked for me too.

Matlab 2012a working fine in nojvm mode now.

Oh, I also did Java update - but I did that before XQuartz reinstall, so not sure if it was needed.