# Mac OSX Mavericks X11 "connection refused"

Tags: osx-mavericks, x11-forwarding

### Summary

I can SSH into a remote Linux box from my macbook, when I am in an Ubuntu Virtual Machine on that macbook - but not from OSX. I seek guidance on how to get OSX to work with X11 forwarding and suspect this is an OSX Mavericks problem. It used to work on Mountain Lion before I upgraded, so I think I missed a step.

Note that this is not [X11/XQuartz won't auto-launch after upgrading to OS X Mavericks?](https://superuser.com/questions/664531/x11-xquartz-wont-auto-launch-after-upgrading-to-os-x-mavericks) as I did a format and clean install of Mavericks

### X11 SERVER - Ubuntu Desktop

```
# This is the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file, trimmed down

# Relevant lines:
X11Forwarding yes
X11UseLocalhost yes
X11DisplayOffset 10

# Maybe relevant:
RSAAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication yes # I didn't want to copy the rsa key into ubuntu VM so I accessed the server by password authentication rather than by rsa key.
TCPKeepAlive yes
```

I can ssh into this machine no problems.

### X11 CLIENT - OSX Mavericks (not working)

I installed [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/) 2.7.5, not sure which version I had on OSX Mountain Lion.

```
# edited /etc/ssh_config to prevent timeout issues

ForwardX11Timeout 596h
```

In the .ssh/config file I have

```
Host remotegossamer
  User joe
  port 22
  Hostname 55.55.55.55 # (edited.. I use no-ip as I have a dynamic ip)
  ForwardX11 yes
  ForwardX11Trusted yes # This gets rid of the warning: "Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated"
```

When I ssh in I get a warning

```
> ssh remotegossamer
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
Welcome to Ubuntu 13.10 (GNU/Linux 3.11.0-15-generic x86_64)
...
```

When I attempt to open an X11 window it fails

```
joe@gossammer:~$ firefox&
[1] 12195
joe@gossammer:~$ connect 127.0.0.1 port 6010: Connection refused

(process:12195): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
connect 127.0.0.1 port 6010: Connection refused
connect 127.0.0.1 port 6010: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: localhost:10.0
^C
[1]+  Exit 1                  firefox
```

The Glib-CRITICAL is a firefox bug which is present for both ubuntu and osx clients, its the server's problem, and can be ignored.

The result of `echo $DISPLAY` is either `localhost:10.0` or `localhost:11.0` depending on whether I ssh in with the current machine first or second. Disconnecting both machines and sshing in in the reverse order has no effect; ubuntu client succeeds with 10 and 11, OSX fails with both.

I read up on this and port 6010 is correct as it starts at port 6000 and counts up in increments of 10, as mentioned in the server's sshd_config.

So I am baffled as to why OSX is not connecting...

I should note that when I used to ssh in from Mountain Lion, the XQuartz app would start - now it does not

### X11 CLIENT - Ubuntu Desktop (In virtual machine on OSX Mavericks)

To configure the ubuntu VM to ssh into the server:

```
# I edited the /etc/ssh/ssh_config to have:
Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
    ForwardX11 yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

Then I ssh'd in with:

```
ssh -Y joe@55.55.55.55
```

and got no warnings. Then, I did:

```
> firefox&
```

And it opened in X11, great, so its a problem with OSX / the way I have set up OSX

### And so

Did I miss something with setting up X11 on OSX Mavericks?

Answer (score 5):

Try the following command (once you're logged in on OS X):

```
export XAUTHORITY=/home/your_name/.Xauthority
```

and then try some innocuous X app, like `xeyes`. If it works, you can put that statement in your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Down to only one error! Progress! `Error: Can't open display: 127.0.0.1:10.0`

Comment: @ClothSword On the server side, do you have, in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, this line: X11UseLocalhost yes ? It should be commented out.

Comment: No that causes more errors, it gives `connect 127.0.0.1 port 6010: Connection refused
connect 127.0.0.1 port 6010: Connection refused
connect 127.0.0.1 port 6010: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: localhost:10.0` note that it was working fine with Ubuntu client so I think its a problem with the mac setup. Hmm, setting it back and these new errors remain...